# Word for defining basic, derived or combined

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word/words that can be used as a label where a user selects one option from either **basic**, **derived** or **combination**.

When talking about an exercise, you could define it as a **basic**, **derived** or **combination**.

Take a squat for example,

- a **basic** squat could be standing normally with toes pointing forward and then bending knees.
- One **derived** version could be adding a little hop added. Another **derived** version could be adding a pause while knees are bent.
- A **combination** is a combination of exercises such as squat + bicep curl.

This is to be used in a software where there is a drop down and a label for the dropdown. The dropdown will contain the 3 options above. It is giving an exercise various properties and I'm trying to come up with an appropriate label, which can't be longer than 2 or 3 words but preferably 1.

So what would such a word(s) be?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest **variant**.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is *squat+hop* "derived", but *pause+hop* is "combination"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think because it's a combination of the two derived versions he mentioned.

Comment: @John: Do you mean *squat+hop* and *squat+pause* are "derived" because they only add *one* extra element, and that the "combination" above actually means *squat+pause+hop*? I still don't see why two elements is "derived", but three is "combination". That's not a feature of ordinary English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't either, but I figured the OP had a particular reason for classifying them as such. I think "variant" works regardless, even if you only had basic and derived.

Comment: I'm closevoting "Unclear"

Comment: The "combination" option is when an exercise is combined with another. I.e. squat + bicep curl. Sorry for not being clear enough, I'm not so familiar with exercises myself either.

Comment: I wonder if this would be better asked on Physical Fitness SE. There doesn't seem to be an *English* question here; it's more of what to call a particular type of exercise.

Comment: I guess it could possibly be asked in Physical Fitness SE even if I don't think it is a general known classification. I chose this SE because I am after an English definition that incorporates the states of "basic", "derived" and "combination". So far 'variant' is a possible option but doesn't feel like a full fit. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear, why are the words used in the question not satisfactory? How do you intend to refer to these things? Adding more information to your question would make it easier to answer.

Comment: I have added information on how this will be used and why. @SuperBiasedMan, I'm not sure which words you refer to that is in the question already, but I hope I've given some more clarity with the edit.

Comment: What isn't helping here is how "derived" and "combination" are arrived at. If squat+hop is *derived,* why is squat+curl *combination*? The problem with asking this as an English question is that the foundation of the question is not easily understood: it's a specialist field for which there is already a specialist Stack Exchange site. Unless I've completely misunderstood and all you are asking for is a word like ***Type*** of exercise.

Comment: What I mean is, why can't you just use "basic", "derived" and "combination"? I can think of reasons they're unsuitable, but why they're unsuitable for your needs is important information.

Comment: @PostureOfLearning Are you asking for replacements for the words you listed, or a label for the whole menu?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, With squat+hop I don't consider the little hop while knees are bent an exercise on it's own, but a sort of 'add-on'. Therefore, squat+hop is a derived version of the basic squat. Say, doing a curl with a weight, can be a basic exercise on its own which is why squat+curl is a combination of 2 exercises. And yes, I'm asking for a word like Type, but I already have that word used for something else.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm looking for a label for 'the menu'/the options.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, I'm looking for a label that defines those 3 options.

Comment: @JohnClifford, I am going with Variant. If you want to post it as an answer I will set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thy will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I think the best word that sums up the choices you specified is **variant**.

> a form or version of something that differs in some respect from other forms of the same thing or from a standard.

Answer (score 0):

For basic, you could use **simple**--one exercise, most basic implementation.

For derived, you could use **advanced**, or perhaps **extended** or **enhanced**, which is simple, with a twist.

For combination, I would just shorten that to **combo**, since it's already reasonably clear given your bicep example.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but I'm not after alternatives for each of these 3, I'm after a word(s) as a label for those 3 options. If you see question comments, you will see that Variant & Type have been suggested.